# MySQL function definition - 'BEGIN' (begin) is not a valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-workbench

I typed this up in verbatim from a textbook on MySQL.

There's a red X denoting an error on the line BEGIN with the text 'BEGIN' (begin) is not a valid input at this position.

The database used is View Ridge Gallery.  Is there any obvious issues with the code?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS InsertCustomerAndInterests;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION InsertCustomerAndInterests
   (
newLastName         Char(25),
newFirstName        Char(25),
newAreaCode         Char(3),
newPhoneNumber      Char(8),
newEmail            Varchar(100),
newNationality      Char(30)
)
  BEGIN

DECLARE varRowCount     Int;
DECLARE varArtistID     Int;
DECLARE varCustomerID   Int;
DECLARE done            Int DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE AristCursor     CURSOR FOR
        SELECT      AristID
        FROM        ARTIST  
        WHERE       Nationality=newNationality;
DECLARE continue        HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

#Check to see if Customer already exists in datebase
SELECT Count(*) INTO varRowCount
FROM    CUSTOMER 
WHERE   LastName = newLastName
    AND FirstName = newFirstName
    AND AreaCode = newAreaCode
    AND PhoneNumber = newPhoneNumber
    AND Email = newEmail;
#IF (varRowCount > 0 ) THEN Customer already exists
IF (varRowCount > 0 ) 
    THEN 
        ROLLBACK; 
        SELECT 'Customer already exists';
    END IF;

#IF (varRowCount = 0 ) THEN Customer does not exist.
#Insert new Customer data
IF (varRowCount = 0)
    THEN 
        INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (LastName, FirstName, AreaCode, PhoneNumber, Email)
        VALUES (newLastName, newFirstName, newAreaCode, newPhoneNumber,        newEmail);
    #Get new CustomerID surrogate key value 
    SET varCustomerID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
#Create intersection record for each appropriate Arist.

OPEN AristCursor;
REPEAT
    FETCH ArtistCursor INTO varArtistArtistID;
        IF NOT done THEN
            INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ARTIST_INT (ArtistID, CustomerID)
                VALUES (varArtistID, varCustomerID);
            END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE ArtistCursor;
SELECT 'New customer and artist interest data added to database.'
    AS InsertCustomerAndInterestsResults;

END IF;
END

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add return type before begin and must return value from the function.

```
 DELIMITER $$

    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `InsertCustomerAndInterests`$$

    CREATE  FUNCTION `InsertCustomerAndInterests`(
    newLastName         CHAR(25),
    newFirstName        CHAR(25),
    newAreaCode         CHAR(3),
    newPhoneNumber      CHAR(8),
    newEmail            VARCHAR(100),
    newNationality      CHAR(30)
    ) RETURNS INT(11) # you missed return type here.
    BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;


            RETURN done; # must match with return type
    END$$

    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: if you swapped out the // with # he could just block run the whole thing. Otherwise you might not get credit because your comments cause syntax errors themselves

Answer (score 0):

Since all functions need a return value and return type, you are missing the `RETURNS` clause after declaring your parameters. See [CREATE FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)